# The asymptotic behavior of hypergeometric function around -1

Tags: special-functions, asymptotics, orthogonal-polynomials

Recently, in studing some specific orthogonal polynomials on unit circle, I was lead to study the asymptotic behavior of the following hypergeometric function at the neighberhood of $-1$:

$$ f_n(e^{i \theta}) = _2\!\!F_1(s, -n; -n-s; e^{i\theta}) = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(s)_k(-n)_k}{(-n-s)_k k!} e^{i k \theta}.$$ What is the asymptotic behavior of $ |f_n(e^{i \theta})|$ when $\theta$ is near $\pi$ ? Do we have some estimate as the Szego type inequalities for Jacobi polynomials?

Does some one know any references related to this? Thank you in advance for any kind of suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I just come across on a paper which answers my own question above. (turns out to be very easy.) Here it is:

By using the transformation of hypergeometric functions \begin{align*} _2F_1\left(\begin{array}{c} a, b \\ c\end{array}; z \right)  = (1-z)^{-a} \, _2F_1\left(\begin{array}{c} a, c - b\\ c \end{array}; \frac{z}{z-1} \right),\end{align*} we have for $\big| \frac{z}{z-1} \big| \le r <1,$ the following uniform expansion: \begin{align*} & _2F_1\left( \begin{array}{c}  s, -n \\ -n - s \end{array}; z  \right) = (1-z)^{-s} {_2F_1}\left( \begin{array}{c}  s, -s \\ -n - s \end{array}; \frac{z}{z-1}  \right) \\ = & (1-z)^{-s} \left[  1 + \frac{s(-s)}{-n - s} \frac{z}{z-1} +  \frac{s(s+1) (-s) (-s + 1)}{ (-n - s) (-n -s +1)} \left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^2 + \cdots \right]  \\ = & (1 - z)^{-s}\left[1 + \mathcal{O} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]. \end{align*}